# Issue with make an UIView fullscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying make a UIView fullscreen but the problem is my view does not cover all the screen here is my code :

```
    PDFView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    PDFView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [PDFView setNeedsLayout];
```

[image]

my app runs only in portrait mode .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not covering the full screen do you mean that the navbar and/or tabbar are still there? If so, check to make sure that you've done these in the view controllers viewDidLoad.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];    
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]
 [self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES]
```

These should take care of anything that would block your fullscreen.

Comment: No I don't have any navigation or tab bar just this 
[self.view addSubView:PDFView];